Updating to Spyder to 6.0.1 - Chosen Path already exists Error
Earlier today i got a pop-up stating Spyder can be updated to 6.0.1. When i try to update it, I get the following error message:

The folder exists and but i am hesitant to delete it, as far as i can tell the current Spyder version is installed there.
I installed spyder initially with Anaconda, but i updated it before with the built-in installer.
I am using a Macbook Air M3 running Sequoia 15.0.1.
